# Even Number Counter with React Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out re-writing "even number counter" example below, by only using functional components instead of class method.

Here is the original one:

Code

```
    class ShouldComponentUpdate extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          value: 0
        }
        this.addValue = this.addValue.bind(this)
      }
    
      addValue () {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          value: state.value + 1
        }))
      }
    
      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.addValue}>Add</button>
            <OnlyEvens value={this.state.value} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    class OnlyEvens extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
      }
    
      shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextProps.value % 2 === 0) return true
      }
    
      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Well, I try to do something below but I lost in callback function. Can someone review please?

Code

```
    function ComponentShouldUpdate () {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Add</button>
          <EvenCounter counter={counter} />
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    const EvenCounter = React.memo(({ counter }) => {
      function checkEven (nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextProps.counter % 2 === 0) {
        //lost in here
        }
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{counter}</h2>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the counter logic into your own custom hook something like `useEvenCounter`. Because hooks are *composable*, it can be reused anywhere else, not just in your particular component

```js
function useEvenCounter(initialValue: number = 0) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);
  const increment = React.useCallback(
    () => setValue((v) => (v % 2 === 0 ? v + 2 : v + 1)),
    []
  );

  return [value, increment] as const;
}
```

### Usage

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, increment] = useEvenCounter();
  const [value2, increment2] = useEvenCounter(1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => increment()}>+</button>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <button onClick={() => increment2()}>+</button>
      <div>{value2}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

You can play around in the live demo below. Hit me up if you don't understand anything

[image: Edit 64433848/even-number-counter-with-react-functional-components]

Comment: Thanks, but main concern is I do not want to re-render on odd numbers. The function should update render only in even numbers. I couldn't figure how to replace shouldComponentUpdate() on functional component instead of using classes.